# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkStructuredCborFactory

Tags: java, spring, aws-sdk

I'm upgrading `amazonaws sdks` in my project

following are the upgrades I did in `POM`

```
amazon-kinesis-client from 1.9.0 to 1.14.9  
amazon-kinesis-producer from 0.10.2 to 0.15.2  
aws-java-sdk-core from 1.11.272 to 1.12.398  
jmespath-java from 1.11.98 to 1.12.398
```

after the changes getting the following runtime errors in log file and my kinesis `consumer`/`worker` are not working. `kinesis-producer` working fine.

```
[ INFO] [] [RecordProcessor-0000] (06 Feb 2023 11:35:49) (KinesisDataFetcher.java:171) - Initializing shard shardId-000000000000 with 49636335084413016973448851393414073031389798471324139522
[ERROR] [] [Thread-10] (06 Feb 2023 11:35:50) (Worker.java:709) - Worker.run caught exception, sleeping for 1000 milli seconds!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkStructuredCborFactory
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisShardConsumer.determineTaskOutcome(KinesisShardConsumer.java:393)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisShardConsumer.checkAndSubmitNextTask(KinesisShardConsumer.java:328)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisShardConsumer.consumeShard(KinesisShardConsumer.java:316)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.runProcessLoop(Worker.java:698)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.run(Worker.java:681)
    at com.hk.web.listener.KinesisConsumer$2.run(KinesisConsumer.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkStructuredCborFactory
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisShardConsumer.determineTaskOutcome(KinesisShardConsumer.java:376)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkStructuredCborFactory
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonProtocolFactory.getSdkFactory(SdkJsonProtocolFactory.java:141)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonProtocolFactory.createGenerator(SdkJsonProtocolFactory.java:55)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonProtocolFactory.createGenerator(SdkJsonProtocolFactory.java:75)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonProtocolFactory.createProtocolMarshaller(SdkJsonProtocolFactory.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.transform.GetShardIteratorRequestProtocolMarshaller.marshall(GetShardIteratorRequestProtocolMarshaller.java:52)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeGetShardIterator(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1420)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.getShardIterator(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1405)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.KinesisProxy.getIterator(KinesisProxy.java:574)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.MetricsCollectingKinesisProxyDecorator.getIterator(MetricsCollectingKinesisProxyDecorator.java:125)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisDataFetcher.getIterator(KinesisDataFetcher.java:224)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisDataFetcher.advanceIteratorTo(KinesisDataFetcher.java:200)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisDataFetcher.initialize(KinesisDataFetcher.java:172)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitializeTask.call(InitializeTask.java:94)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:49)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

I was checking if both my kiensis `producer` & `consumer` are working fine or not, `producer` is working fine after the upgrade, but kinesis `consumer`/`worker` are giving the error I mentioned.

Comment: Is `com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkStructuredCborFactory` on your classpath/modulepath? Is there another `Caused By` section in the stack trace you omitted?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix, needed to upgrade the com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind from 2.6.x to 2.12.x+ and that resolved the error.
thanks everyone who responded.